# Sonar-scanner, permission denied, from docker container

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am trying to run sonar-scanner command as  node-module. My sonarqube is running inside a docker container and working fine, i can see from localhost:9000.

But sonar-scanner is giving error like this:

```
 > sonar-scanner

/home/raju/angular/anfxaaa/node_modules/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner: 59: exec: : Permission denied.
```

How can i execute this sonar-scanner from terminal. I dont have much linux file permission idea.

```
 raju@ubuntu:~/angular/nfx/node_modules/sonar-scanner/bin$ ls -l sonar-scanner
-rwxrwxrwx 1 raju raju 1646 Apr 19  2018 sonar-scanner
raju@ubuntu:~/angular/nfx/node_modules/sonar-scanner/bin$ ./sonar-scanner
./sonar-scanner: 59: exec: : Permission denied
```

Please help

Comment: check the user permission for sonar-scanner

Comment: i tried chmod 777 ./sonar-scanner,  by going into node_modules folder, but still premission issue.

Comment: @raju did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
addgroup sonar && \
useradd -s ${whoami} -d ${SONAR_SCANNER_HOME} -g sonar sonar
```